# Alexa- audio issue

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

```
var Response = require('alexa-response');

//first intent
LaunchRequest:function(){
//Type 1 gives an error saying the "response is not valid" when tested in the     developers console.   
//the Response here is an npm library
Response.directives(
AudioPlayer.play({ url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sounds226/boom.mp3' }),
AudioPlayer.enqueue({ url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sounds226/boom.mp3' }                                    ) .build();

//Type 2 : gives an error when tested on echosim.io saying that the response is not valid
speechOutput = this.t('WELCOME_MESSAGE');    this.response.audioPlayerPlay("REPLACE_ALL",audioData[1].url).speak(speechOutput);
this.emit(':responseReady');

//Type 3: tried to insert the audio tag within the speech response, error again
speechOutput = {
speech: "<speak>" +message+ "<audio src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sounds226/boom.mp3'/></speak>",
    type : 'SSML' 
};
response.ask(speechOutput);
}
```

I am trying to insert an audio before alexa speaks in my skill. The audio is well within 90 sec. Is it the way I am understanding the audio tag wrong or using the directives in a wrong way? Thank you in advance. Any help is appreciated

Comment: about ssml - please check more strictly, for example in slikk test tab in developer.amazon.com (not in aws lambda test!)

Comment: Have you enabled audio player direction in you amazon skills setup

Comment: Yes, but the requirements did not need the audio directives. I was trying to figure out how to add an **audio sample** which should be played before Alexa spoke which is not similar to an **audio directives**. I achieved that by  `speechOutput = this.t('WELCOME_MESSAGE')+'<audio src='+url+'/>';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is intro with examples:

https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/new-alexa-skills-kit-ask-feature-audio-streaming-in-alexa-skills

and there is clear information:

When responding to a LaunchRequest or IntentRequest, your response can include both AudioPlayer directives and standard response properties such as outputSpeech, card, and reprompt. **For example, if you provide outputSpeech in the same response as a Play directive, Alexa speaks the provided text before beginning to stream the audio.**

Doc - https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference

More about start play

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference#play

Comment: I have having an issue adding the audio tag, but later was able to do so by doing the following: speechOutput = this.t('WELCOME_MESSAGE')+'<audio src='+url+'/>'; and it worked. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `<audio>` tag in the SSML response, make sure the MP3 file conforms to the sample rate (16000) and bitrate (48kbps) required by Alexa.

[More details here.](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#h3_converting_mp3.)

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0 Thanks a lot for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Audio should be encoded to specific format(Project Rate 16000 and Quality to 48 kbps) for Alexa to play it. Please convert your audio using below command,

ffmpeg -i  -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 16000

You can download 'ffmpeg ' from https://www.ffmpeg.org/

If you are using windows CD to the bin folder of ffmeg before run above command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the format of your audio clip. It's given on the SSML page of Alexa documentation
2. Make sure your audio clip is as per that format.